# how do you use rest to put a .csv file onto a storage account?

Tags: azure, powershell, rest, azure-storage

how do you use resenter code heret to upload data to a storage account in the format of .csv

1. Get token
2. Get Request using invoke-rest method.
3. export data in csv to a storage account

   $Request = Invoke-RestMethod @ParamRequest

   Request.value.properties | export-csv -path $path -NoTypeInformation

API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usage-details/list

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use REST API instead of directly using Azure PowerShell cmdlets? Also, your question lack details. Please provide more details.

Comment: Yes, I am using powershell cmdlets to invoke rest-method. The problem I am having is, how do I put it into a storage account?

Comment: You don't really need to do that (invoke rest-method). You can simply use [`Set-AzStorageBlobContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/set-azstorageblobcontent?view=azps-6.4.0) to upload a CSV file in Azure Storage.

Comment: no, the data comes from the invoke rest-method. The .csv stored on my computer is what is I don't need because it needs to already be stored on the storage account. So the question is still, how do I put data into the storage account into a .csv file format?

Comment: But in your PowerShell code you're writing the content to a CSV file (`export-csv -path $path -NoTypeInformation`). Is that you want to avoid and directly convert the response data into CSV format and upload it?

Comment: that's correct.

Comment: Got it. Do you have access to storage account name and key?

Comment: yes. the idea is to have this script run in an azure automation account on a schedule, maybe once a month.

Comment: to re-iterate, yes i have access to the storage account name and key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a PowerShell expert :) but essentially the idea is to create a Shared Access Signature (SAS) URL for the blob and then use that SAS URL for uploading the content directly into Azure Storage.

Here's what I came up with:

```
$accountName = "storage-account-name"
$accountKey = "storage-account-key"
$containerName = "blob-container-name"
$blobName = "blob-name.csv"

# Get storage context
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $accountKey

# Get Shared Access Signature (SAS) Token expiration time. I have set it to expire after 1 hour.
$sasExpiry = (Get-Date).AddHours(1).ToUniversalTime()

# Get a SAS Token with "write" permission that will expire after one hour.
$sasToken =  New-AzStorageBlobSASToken -Context $context -Container $containerName -Blob $blobName -Permission "w" -ExpiryTime $sasExpiry

# Create a SAS URL
$sasUrl = "https://$accountName.blob.core.windows.net/$containerName/$blobName$sasToken"

# Set request headers
$headers = @{"x-ms-blob-type":"BlockBlob"}

# Set request content (body)

$body = "This is the content I wish to upload"

#Invoke "Put Blob" REST API

Invoke-RestMethod -Method "PUT" -Uri $sasUrl -Body $body -Headers $headers -Content-Type "text/csv"
```

Comment: Not sure if this means anything, but yes I understand that you use the SAS url from the blob container to upload content directly into Azure storage. I am now getting Invoke-RestMethod: Authentication Failed Server failed to authenticate request. make sure the value of authorization header is formed correctly including the signature

Comment: Please edit your question and include the complete code and I will take a look. This error usually means there is something with your SAS token.

Comment: yes, you're right, the problem was the sas token needs to exist at the blob level, not the container. I need to adjust the invoke-restmethod to write a file at the container level. and thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You can also create a SAS token at the container level. You just have to use [New-AzStorageContainerSASToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontainersastoken?view=azps-6.4.0) instead of New-AzStorageBlobSASToken. HTH.