# How to Dynamically write a export CSV file to Azure blob container using PowerShell?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I have an Azure Powershell command that exports VM Metric information.

```
(Get-AzMetric -ResourceID $id -StartTime $s -EndTime -MetricName $metric).Data |Export-Csv -Path $blobpath
```

`$blobpath` I have given as a SAS URL of the blob Container.

I want to add the blobpath for the -Path parameter but getting the error "Can not find drive".

[image: Cannot find drive error]

Comment: Please edit your question and include the PS command you're using for uploading the blob.

Comment: @Gaurav - its the SAS URL which contains the blobURL+SAS token+csvfilename

Comment: Thanks. `Export-Csv` can only write to local file system. What you have to do is first write to the file system and then upload the blob by using `Set-AzBlobContent`.

Comment: Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69363235/how-do-you-use-rest-to-put-a-csv-file-onto-a-storage-account/69365170#69365170) if you don't want to write a CSV file to disk first and then upload. HTH.

Comment: @Gaurav - Thank you for the answer. I also referred your another answer regarding addition of &comp=list&restype=container to the SAS URL. But still its failing for me with the Server error 409 and its mainly due to the Public access is blocked to the Storage. I tried to execute it from cloud shell as well as from ADO. But due to the access issue its not working for me. But both the answers highlighted below seems to be correct to me. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @YogeshKulkarni, If below  answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestion  [Gaurav Mantri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri)

**Solution 1:** First you need to save the exported csv file in local system then you need to upload it to container in azure storage. I tried it in my system

Use [**Set-AzStorageBlobContent**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/set-azstorageblobcontent?view=azps-6.5.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-5.4.0) cmdlet to upload this .csv file to blob storage

Try with these steps

**1)** generate a context by using **[New-AzStorageContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontext?view=azps-6.5.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-5.4.0)**

```
$sas_token="SAS”
$account_name = "your_storage_account_name"


$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $account_name -SasToken $sas_token
```

**2)** use **Set-AzStorageBlobContent**  to upload csv file to blob storage

```
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container "the container name" -File " file path Ex: c:\myfolder\test.csv" " -Context $context
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

The file uploaded to azure container

[image]

**Solution 2:** Upload the content directly to Azure storage by using sas Url.

Try with this commands

```
$accountName = "storage-account-name"
$accountKey = "storage-account-key"
$containerName = "blob-container-name"
$blobName = "blob-name.csv"

# Get storage context
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $accountKey

# Get Shared Access Signature (SAS) Token expiration time. e.g. set to expire after 1 hour:
$sasExpiry = (Get-Date).AddHours(1).ToUniversalTime()

# Get a SAS Token with "write" permission that will expire after one hour.
$sasToken =  New-AzStorageBlobSASToken -Context $context -Container $containerName -Blob $blobName -Permission "w" -ExpiryTime $sasExpiry

# Create a SAS URL
$sasUrl = "https://$accountName.blob.core.windows.net/$containerName/$blobName$sasToken"

# Set request headers
$headers = @{"x-ms-blob-type"="BlockBlob"}

# Set request content (body)

$body = "This is the content I wish to upload"

#Invoke "Put Blob" REST API

Invoke-RestMethod -Method "PUT" -Uri $sasUrl -Body $body -Headers $headers -ContentType "text/csv"
```

"