# is it possible to create blobs in a storage account using powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage

I see plenty of information on how to move/copy/upload files to blob storage, but I don't see any information on how to **create blobs**.

Suppose we have :
`$fileContents`:

```
$fileContents= @"
{
'my data':'lots of stuff'
}
"@
```

**How do we create a blob from `$fileContents`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the existing Azure Blobs PowerShell Cmdlets, only way you can create blobs is by uploading a file using [`Set-AzStorageBlobContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/set-azstorageblobcontent?view=azps-6.6.0) which is not something you want.

Other option for you would be to create a SAS token with appropriate permission and then use `Invoke-RestMethod` to invoke Azure Blob Storage REST API. I answered a similar question some time ago that you may find useful: [how do you use rest to put a .csv file onto a storage account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69363235/how-do-you-use-rest-to-put-a-csv-file-onto-a-storage-account).

Comment: i dont believe you are correct. i've been able to before create a blob by passing in simple text, without having a pre-existing file

Comment: What version of Azure PS Cmdlets did you use for that? AFAIK, Set-AzStorageBlobContent is the only way to upload blobs (I may be wrong though).

Comment: https://blog.zuehlke.cloud/2020/06/upload-and-download-blobs-in-azure-storage-without-local-files/

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. This is using the SDK in PowerShell. I guess you can go down this path if you’re comfortable consuming the SDK in PS code. I thought you were looking for a solution where you were only using the Cmdlets available.

Comment: really appreciate all of your helpful comments and answers thank yo so much