# How do I upload a buffer directly to a Azure storage blob in PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, serverless

I have a serverless powershell function that creates image data from an algorithm and stores it in a `$buffer`. I'd like to save this `$buffer` to a blob container as foobar.png. However, [Set-AzStorageBlobContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/Set-AzStorageBlobContent) reads from a file, and all the examples I have found involve saving a temporary file to local disk (which I don't have the ability to do in a serverless environment).

Anyone have an example of the best way to do this?

Comment: Could you please refer this MS DOC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-powershell#upload-blobs-to-the-container

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69889232/is-it-possible-to-create-blobs-in-a-storage-account-using-powershell/69889335#69889335.